# How to connect to database using scripting language inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, mysql, r, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Using Google Kubernetes Engine, I have set up a mysql database deployment & service in kubernetes, much like the [wordpress example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/). I want to access it via R with R which I have in another deployment & service in my kubernetes cluster (r-user-app, w/2 containers). This worked with networks in docker.

```
> kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                         AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.15.240.1     <none>           443/TCP                         8d
mysql        LoadBalancer   10.15.248.129   35.227.123.232   3306:31410/TCP                  3m
r-user-app   LoadBalancer   10.15.255.135   35.227.33.206    3838:31003/TCP,8787:32395/TCP   1d
```

Exec into the rstudio container inside the `r-user-app` deployment, I see the mysql service:

```
root@r-user-app-1788932656-vgczh:/# getent hosts mysql
10.15.248.129   mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
```

However, when I try to get it via R, I have no such luck:

```
root@r-user-app-1788932656-vgczh:/# R
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
-----
> require("RMySQL")
Loading required package: RMySQL
Loading required package: DBI
> mydb<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user="root", password="mypassword", host="10.15.248.129")
Error in .local(drv, ...) :
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.15.248.129' (107)
```

Using the `EXTERNAL-IP` doesn't work either, and putting `port=3306` doesn't help.

Same thing in python:

```
> db=MySQLdb.connect("10.15.248.129", "root", "mypassword")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'10.15.248.129\' (111 "Connection refused")')
```

Maybe I don't even know the right question to ask! Please help! #kubenube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: This was an issue with the yaml. Needed to be sure to match the `Service`

```
  selector:
    app: my-app
    tier: mysql
```

and the `Deployment`

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
      tier: mysql
```

Now we can access the database using "mysql" instead of a host IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the IP. You can access the servers directly by name. You even don't need to use the full DNS name with "mysql.default.svc.cluster.local", just "mysql" is enough.

You should also check the mysql pod, if it is deployed properly. Using `Type=LoadBalancer` is not a good idea for databases, as it opens them to the outer network.

Comment: Steinman        Thank you so much for a quick answer but when I tried that I get the same error. I will switch back to ClusterIP only.                `db<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password ='neurocoreai',
+                  host =  "mysql", port=3306)
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (107)`

Comment: it looks like a network issue...it actually should work

Comment: is this a GCE thing? Pinging the mysql service comes back empty: `root@r-user-app-1788932656-vgczh:/# ping mysql
PING mysql.default.svc.cluster.local (10.15.245.25): 56 data bytes`

Comment: is your mysql pod running well? check out the logs of the pod behind mysql

Comment: `20:32:44 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2018-01-17 20:32:44 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2018-01-17 20:32:44 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2018-01-17 20:32:44 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-01-17 20:32:44 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@mysql-3648550465-lmzxc' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-01-17 20:32:44 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-01-17 20:32:44 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.39'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)`